# How do I match pattern before the main expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry if the context of this question feels like it has been asked before.
I am new here and new to RegEx as well.

I have been trying to solve a problem and partially solved it using http://regexr.com (Wonderful site!)

> There are 3 types of gifts of color: Red(R), Saffron(S), White(W). You want to select only Saffron gifts.
>   It is believed that the Saffron gift which is next to White gift is 'not good' and the Saffron gift neighboring to 'not good' (S) gift is also 'not good'. You want to give only good gifts to your friend.
>   Red gifts close to 'not good' gifts remain good"**

Basically, S in ...RSR... is good, but shouldn't be next to WSW or SWS group.
SSSS...S is fine.

[Sample case](http://regexr.com/3gggp):

```
WSSSRSSWSSW
SSSSSS
SRSRSSSSSSR
SRWSSWRSRWSSWSRSS
```

[image]

```
/S(?!S*W)/g
```

I used this and it works except for S in WSSS (first line of text) and the last one.

How do I solve that?
Thanks for your time (:

Comment: what about WSS ? the S is also not good so would the last S be valid ?

Comment: That would be bad because S next to W is bad and S next to bad is bad. -- R is always good, but you only want S gifts, right? - So effectively R is non-spoiling bad and W is spoiling bad. - So since the S next to the S next to the W is spoiled, it too would be bad, so any further S until R would be bad too. (i.e. WSSSSSSSRS) only the last S is a good gift.

Comment: Are [in this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/wTEoUM/1) the green ones ([captures](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) of group 1) the good ones or is it not correct?

Comment: @bobblebubble I don't see any matches in that demo

Comment: in the 4th case the 3rd matched S is wrong see my new answer

Comment: well, my demo has error :p @marvel308 vote already yours neat one. Julix not sure if yours matches such like `SWS` as desired (similar my demo error).

Comment: I added a new answer which would match everything in the 2nd group, I feel it is cleaner since it exactly matches what is required in the 2nd group, you can update the image using that

Comment: although it would match R also, not sure if you can highlight just the 2nd group :P

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getValidS(str){
 str = str.replace(/(S*W+S*)/g, '').replace(/R/g, '');
 console.log(str);
}
getValidS("WSSSRSSWSSW");
getValidS("SSSSSS");
getValidS("SRSRSSSSSSR");
getValidS("SRWSSWRSRWSSWSRSS");
```

getValidS() returns all valid S

Comment: Yup, the correction fixed it. Didn't see you were working on that, so I gave it a try of my own and am getting the same result. It's okay, but it's not perfect, in terms of following the instructions, since we're selecting all the things that aren't a match and taking those out. Technically we're supposed to select the ones that are a match...

Comment: @marvel308 Hey! That works! Thanks! (: But I think Julix is right, I want a regex for matching the S rather than finding out what doesn't match. Do you think you can do that? Thanks!

Comment: @Julix Hey! Thanks for your input. Yes! I specifically want the regex for matching rather than finding out what doesn't match! (:

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on it replacing all the things that aren't a good gift rather than directly trying to select a good gift. Function structure taken from marvel308, regex my own.

```js
function getValidS(str){
 str = str.replace(/((W+S+)|(S+W+)|R|W)/g, '');
 console.log(str);
}
getValidS("WSSSRSSWSSW");
getValidS("SSSSSS");
getValidS("SRSRSSSSSSR");
getValidS("SRWSSWRSRWSSWSRSS");
```

Comment: Hey @Julix It works! (: Can you select the match directly? I am more interested in that. I have been working hard to find that but failed. I think I could have done it if there was positive lookbehind feature in javascript?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment below, use this Pattern instead and check against capturing group #1

`S*W+S*|(S+)`

```
S           # "S"
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
W           # "W"
+           # (one or more)(greedy)
S           # "S"
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
|           # OR
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  S         # "S"
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

Comment: thanks for your input but it doesn't work as intended :(
You missed out S in the first and last cases and it is also selecting the R!

Comment: @ManpreetKrishan, I misunderstood the requirements, check my updated pattern.

Comment: it is selecting the W as well, which I don't require and also the S along with them. What you did is what I DON'T want, which is the other correct form of answer. So I need to eliminate this W and S and also R and get the other S. I need the other form of answer without this one. More like the complement of your answer. If you have any doubts, let me know.

Comment: @ManpreetKrishan, Check against Capturing Group #1 ONLY.

Comment: I am still new to Regex, learning it. Your answer will be useful. Thanks (:

Answer (score 1):

I had another attempt at this basically the S is valid if it is between start|R and end|R so the regex would become

> (^|R)(S+)(?=R|$)/gi

```js
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
  index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[index]);
  }
  console.log(matches);
  return matches;
}

var regexp = /(^|R)(S+)(?=R|$)/gi;
getMatches('WSSSRSSWSSW', regexp, 2);
getMatches('SRWSSWRSRWSSWSRSS', regexp, 2);
getMatches('SSSSSS', regexp, 2);
getMatches('SRSRSSSSSSR', regexp, 2);
```

[image: The red highlight denotes the 2nd group]

here the red highlighted part refers to the 2nd group which is the desired match

Comment: It seems to be working here, but not on http://regexr.com/ :/ Why so? it selects the R as well, do you have any direct approach?

Comment: yes it matches R also but captures S in the 2nd group, you can just match the 2nd group always, the index in the code represents which group I am matching

Comment: since javascript doesn't support lookbehinds we would have to match R in 1 of the groups but that doesn't need to be their in the selected groups

Comment: refer to the image I added

Comment: if you don't want to capture the first group use (?:^|R)(S+)(?=R|$) this will just capture the S

Comment: this is also a smart idea!